# Remove inner space in h1 tag

Tags: html, css, alignment, inline

Hi im a beginner in HTML and CSS! Im trying to get the proper alignment of a logo  and a title . Both of them should be on the same line. The problem is that i cant remove the inner space of the h1 and there is always a margin on top of the text (if i color the bg for the h1, i see that it extends further above the text). Is there a way to solve this or am i doing it wrong? I want both of them to be exactly the same height and in the exact same horizontal position (the top of the "T" in title should be at the top of the img and the same for bottom).

HTML:

```
<header>
    <img src="images/logo.gif" alt="logo">
    <h1>Title</h1>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header
{
    overflow:auto;
}

header img
{
    float:left;
    width:55px;
    height:55px;
    margin-right:20px;
}

header h1
{
    float:left;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    font-size:55px;
}
```

Comment: You can use `line-height: 55px;` in `header h1` to fix the problem as the background is concerned, but you have to adjust the font-size manually since the text height varies across different fonts.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256211/negative-margins-vs-relative-positioning

Comment: U'd better use ur `img` like `background` for `h1`. Also u'll add `padding-left` for `h1` in that case.

Comment: I suggest you to use css reset to over come problems like this - http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The line-height: 55px; + some font size adjustment solved it perfectly. Will also look more into the css reset, very interesting for future work.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the line-height to a fixed value?

```
h1 { line-height: 55px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a negative margin-top to your header h1:

```
header h1 {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 55px;
  **margin-top: -15px;**
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a jsfiddle for you .. let me know if this is wat you are trying to achieve -

[JSFiddle ALignment - H1 and IMG](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/kvFHJ/2/show)

```
  header
 {
overflow:auto;
      }

header img
 {
float:left;
width:55px;
height:55px;
margin-right:20px;
margin-top:10px;/*add this */
}
```

Comment: This almost solved it. The alignment was correct but the text box extends down under the end of the image. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Thats because I have set the height of the text box equivalent to the size of the image ... added a new example with texts .. check jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

The negative margin is an option, like ssbrewster suggested, but if you don't want to mess up your layout you could try `line-height`:

```
header h1 {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 55px;
    line-height: 70%;
}
```