# How to prevent <H1>'s from taking up more height than they need

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

It's possible that the `<h1>` tag use only the height that the font need?

If you look at the fiddle example above you will see spaces at the top and bottom, i think 4px. I need to remove that.

Css:

```
.tmp {background-color: green;}
```

HTML:

```
<h1 class="tmp">Hello World</h1>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dx25tzru/

Comment: Already answered on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895962/remove-inner-space-in-h1-tag

Comment: Probably if you set `line-height` with the same size of font. But also remember that it depends of font family to use or not all pixels to draw each letter

Comment: You can always customize your `Bootstrap` download to fix such things (margins, border-radius, line-height, font, etc etc). See http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ You can change almost every part of Bootstrap.

Comment: You can set a smaller line-height than the font if you want to, demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/dx25tzru/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the line height of the h1 equal to its font size:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
line-height:20;
```

or change the line height according to your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

with css you can do :

```
line-height:24px;
```

Comment: try it ... you will see that's wouldn't fix the problem

Comment: I thought you meant the white space before the green...http://jsfiddle.net/6t2k1otL/

Comment: you can play with `line-height` : line-height:24px;