# css relative positioning breaks div into new line

Tags: html, css

I have the following fiddle for this question: http://jsfiddle.net/jcb9xm44/

There are 2 inline-block div's in a parent div:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner1">
       Y
    </div>
    <div class="inner2">
        X
    </div>    
</div>
```

The css assigns a width to the parent div and 2 widths to the child div's.

```
.outer {
    width: 210px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.inner1 {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    display: inline-block;
}
.inner2 {
    width: 50px;
    position:relative;
    left: -50x;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid lightblue;}
```

I was expecting that both divs appear on the same line. Although the parent is not wide enough to hold both children, since the second child has a negative offset, it should be possible to fit them both on the same line. Why does it break the line?

Comment: Add `margin-left: -50px;` - http://jsfiddle.net/2jgag2zs/

Comment: Why did you expect so? widths of the nested divs exceed the available space inside the parent.

Comment: Great. But why does the margin help and the offset doesn't?

Comment: considering that I offset the element to the left, it wouldn't execeed the full width. That's why I ask this question.

Comment: @shaft `left`/`right`/.. properties  -unlike `margin` - won't move a `relative` positioned element physically so that the occupied space would be remain.

Comment: @Hashem. Thanks for the explanation. But still confusing: from w3schools (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_left.asp): >For relatively positioned elements, the left property sets the left edge of an element to a unit to the left/right to its normal position.

Comment: @shaft First of all, please avoid referring low quality resources such as w3schools for learning purposes. using offset properties on `relative` positioned element just moves the element visually but the element is still there at its real position logically, Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256211/negative-margins-vs-relative-positioning

Comment: @HashemQolami Wasn't aware that w3schools is low quality, typically it ranks top one on google when I search for css. Anyway, your explanation is very clear! The logical space vs physical space ;) This helps a lot !

Comment: @shaft Personally, I'd rather refer to the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/#tr_CSS), however you may find [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/) or [Web Platform](http://www.webplatform.org/) more understanable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why does it break the line?

As you stated, it's because the parent element isn't wide enough for both elements. To change this behavior, you could add `white-space: nowrap` to the parent element in order to prevent the `inline-block` elements from wrapping.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljxy08rq/)

```
.outer {
    width: 210px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position:relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Side notes:

- You had a typo - `left: -50x` -> `left: -50px`.
- `inline` elements [respect whitespace in the markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038799/why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-inline-block-div-elements/19038859#19038859).
- The element's border is included in its width calculations. Use `box-sizing: border-box` to include it.
- You could alternatively use `margin-left: -50px` as [Mary Melody pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331205/css-relative-positioning-breaks-div-into-new-line/26331227#comment41326137_26331205).

Comment: Thanks a lot. A comment above mentions also a trick with negative margin. Which one would you recommend? It's also confusing that a negative margin does not have the same effect as offsetting the div. Any explanation for this?

Comment: @shaft Maybe this example I made will help you understand - http://jsfiddle.net/tqzxh0wo/ The margin will affect other elements whereas the relative positioning won't.