# Difference between margin and position

Tags: html, css, web

actually I am beginner in web design and I took the concepts of margin and position properties in css.

So, my question is I can change the position of an element using css properties (position, top and left and so on). 
But also I realized that by increasing the margins and padding, I can also change the position of an element. But is this way good?

Or just there are different ways to change the position of elements?
Which one is better?

Comment: _...is this way good?_ No! it is just a side effect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Negative margins vs relative positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256211/negative-margins-vs-relative-positioning)

Comment: To answer this yourself you will need to understand two things: - The so called "box model", e.g here:
[http://www.htmldog.com - Margins and Padding](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/margins/) - Methods of positioning, e.g. here: [www.w3schools.com - CSS Positioning](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question is actually related to [Box-Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Box_model) which is controlled by [Box-Sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) and others properties:

1. [padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding)
2. [margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin)
3. [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)
4. [border](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border)

Strictly speaking, these properties control the box layout according to the box-model. Since not all part are obvious particularly `margin`, it may seem as it controls positioning but no.

Answer (score 0):

Margin is: how much is the minimal distance from an element to its surrounding element

---

Position property (the important ones) are static, absolute, fixed, relative

Static means that no changes to current position (default)

Relative means that, from the default position, the element will be positioned 'offset' to its default position

Absolute means that the element will be removed from flow and positioned relative to its non-static parent element

Fixed means that the element will be removed from flow and positioned relative to the browser

---

here is reference of positioning:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

here is reference of css box model

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Answer (score -2):

> Margin: To define the spacing out of an element w.r.t. to the element
>   occupied area.
>
> Padding: To define the spacing inside of an element w.r.t. the content
>   of that element.
>
> Position: To define the position of an element w.r.t. the space for
>   content displayed on the screen.

Try it out in W3Schools.com.